# perform a reducer action on physical back button press in react native only in a specific screen

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation, back, react-navigation-v5

I have a case where I have a bottom tab navigator in my app. The first bottom tab is a stack navigator consisting of the main home screen and a siteDetail Screen . The user can navigate from the main home screen to the SiteDetail screen. Likewise, there are other elements in the bottom tab as well.

Whenever the user presses backbutton when he is in the SiteDetail screen, he is directed back to the main home page(that's obvious). But before that I need to update the reducer. So I implemented a BackHandler listener as:

```
constructor(props){
super(props);
//.........
   this.handleBackButtonClick = this.handleBackButtonClick.bind(this);
}       

componentDidMount() {
    
    this.fetchSiteDetail();
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButtonClick);
}

handleBackButtonClick() {
   
    if (this.props.isRestroDetailPage) {// doesn't  work of course
        this.props.unselectSite();
    }
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress');
}
```

The backhandler words well as intended. But, it also works when I traverse to other bottom tabs and press back button. I easily customized the soft back button but for the hard one, the listener listens to presses from all over the bottom tabs.

I do understand this behaviour, but how can I make the program to apply the `this.props.unselectSite()` only when I press the backbutton when I am at SiteDetail screen.
I am using react navigation v5, if that is in anyway helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a conditional before execute the action, the react-native have a props to verify if the screen is select.
A example:

```
handleBackButtonPressAndroid = () => {
    let { navigation } = this.props;
    if (navigation.isFocused()) {
      //execute what you want.
    };
}
```

In your case:

```
handleBackButtonClick() {
    let { navigation } = this.props;
    if(navigation.isFocused()) {
      if (this.props.isRestroDetailPage) {// doesn't  work of course
          this.props.unselectSite();
      }
    }
}
```

Docs: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop/

Comment: Simple and as I wanted it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

React-Navigation just added a new method that should help you out here, [beforeRemove](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/preventing-going-back).

Something like this:

```
React.useEffect(
    () =>
      navigation.addListener('beforeRemove', (e) => {
        if (!props.isRestroDetailPage) {
          // If we don't have unsaved changes, then we don't need to do anything
          return;
        }

        // Prevent default behavior of leaving the screen
        e.preventDefault();

        this.props.unselectSite();
        navigation.dispatch(e.data.action)
      }),
    [navigation, props.isRestroDetailPage]
  );
```